# How can I add multiple items at the same time that have foreign key but I want to assign them later in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

Let's say We have 3 Models in Django

**Network Group Model**, **Ports Model** and **Service Type Model**.

Note: Network Group is like the patch panel that have 24 ports (For Poeple who knows networking)

Each Network Group has usually 24 Ports and each **Port** belongs to One Network Group.

But Each Port have Service Type (ex: Access Point, TV, etc..) and Each Service Type has one Port.

So I m when I m creating Network Group I m generating 24 ports automatically but I don't know how to make the foreign key of service type null so I can assign it once I need it.

Comment: Why would you do this? Create cars and engines as and when you need them, not before!

Comment: @Shadow That's What I really want.. I updated my question

Comment: if a port is a service type can no others be the same type?

Comment: Yes it could be other have the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking it in the wrong way. Try to do like this:

```
Class NetworkGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

Class ServiceType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

Class Port(models.Model):
    network_group = models.ForeignKey('NetworkGroup', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='network_ports')
    service_type = models.ForeignKey('ServiceType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='service_ports')
    ...
```

First add network instance and service instance. Then you can create port and link them with foreignkey. This is the proper way of doing it.

If you want to filter:

```
Port.objects.filter(network_group.name = 'network1') # all ports belong to 'network1'
Port.objects.filter(service_type.name = 'tv') # all ports have service type 'tv'
Port.objects.filter(network_group.name = 'network1', service_type.name = 'tv') # network1 and tv ports
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps me alot :)
But Now How to update my service_type and assign it a value?

Comment: Edited the answer. Fill the name fields in NetworkGroup and ServiceType. Ex: NetworkGroup.name = 'network1', ServiceType.name='tv'. Later add it to Port when creating port. ng=NetworkGroup.objects.filter(name='network1'), st=ServiceType.objects.filter(name='tv'), p=Port(),p.network_group=ng,p.service_type=st